# How to form the simultaneous equation?

Tags: integration

> The gradient function of a curve is $px^2–qx$, where $p$ and $q$ are constants. The curve has a turning point at $(2,–8)$. The gradient of the tangent to the curve at the point where its $x$-coordinate $= –1$ is $6$. Find the value of $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient at the turning point is $0$ so
$$
\begin{align}
4p–2q = 0 \\
2p = q
\end{align}
$$

The gradient when $x = -1$ is $6$ so

$$
p + q = 6
$$

Can you solve the simultaneous equations?